Maximum Likelihood Estimation - Nested(?) Distributions
I am trying to estimate the parameters of an underlying Beta distribution using observations that arise from Geometric distributions that are conditional on the draws from the aforementioned Beta distribution. I am implementing a maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) approach. I apologise in advance for not knowing the correct terminology for this kind of problem.
The risk for each individual $i$, i.e.  $\lambda_{i}$, is distributed according to a Beta distribution.
$\lambda_{i} \sim Beta(\alpha, \beta)$.
Conditional on the risk parameter $\lambda_{i}$, the time to cancellation for individual $i$, i.e. $y_{i}$, is itself stochastic and distributed following a Geometric distribution.
$y_{i} \sim Geometric(\lambda_{i})$
Using the vector of observed times to cancellation, i.e. $\mathbf{y}$, I am trying to recover the underlying $\alpha$ and $\beta$ parameters. I am ``integrating out'' the individual $\lambda_{i}$ by taking the average across 100 constant draws per individual.
I have the following questions:

This feels to me that it must be a very common problem in econometrics. Does this type of problem have a proper name?
I was approaching this using Maximum Simulated Likelihood Estimation (MSLE). I was trying to copy the intuition from https://barumpark.com/blog/2019/MSL/. Does this feel like a kind of problem which should be solved via MSLE to you? Or should it be solved using a different method?
Should I be worried about identification? To me it seems that it should be fairly straight-forward that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are identified, as more left-leaning Beta distributions should give longer times to cancellations, while shorter times to cancellations should indicate a right-leaning Beta distribution.

Any feedback about this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance.
The following code (written in Julia) reproduces what I've done so far.
using Optim
using Distributions

# define the number of consumers
nb_consumers = 2000

# initialise the beta distribution
my_beta = Beta(0.5, 15)

# make the risk type draws
risk_types = rand(my_beta, nb_consumers)

# define their cancellation probability distribution
my_cancellation = Geometric.(risk_types)

# make the cancellation day draws
days_alive = rand.(my_cancellation, 1)

# flatten it into one vector
days_alive = collect(Iterators.flatten(days_alive))

# draw the uniform shocks
eps = rand(Uniform(0, 1), (nb_consumers, 100))

# define a function that takes parameters, y, and eps and evaluates the PDF of a beta
function nested_log_likelihood(shape1, shape2, y, eps)
    # initialise a beta
    temp_beta = Beta(shape1, shape2)
    # compute the risk types
    temp_risk_types = quantile(temp_beta, eps)
    # compute the PDF of the geometric distribution for each
    temp_ll = loglikelihood.(Geometric.(temp_risk_types), y)
    # take the average across the columns
    temp_ll_means = mean(eachcol(temp_ll))
    # sum up and take the negative
    neg_ll = -1 * sum(temp_ll_means)
    println("The negative likelihood is $neg_ll, with parameters at $shape1 and $shape2")
    # return the negative log-likelihood
    return neg_ll
end

# define the anonymous function
anon_nested_log_likelihood = β -> nested_log_likelihood(exp(β[1]), exp(β[2]), days_alive, eps)

anon_nested_log_likelihood([log(0.5), log(15.0)])

# run the optimiser
res = Optim.optimize(
    anon_nested_log_likelihood,
    [log(0.5), log(15.0)]
)


Rather than taking the average of the 100 values for an individual, the sum of those 100 values has a beta negative binomial distribution with parameters $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $n=100$.  Maximizing the log of the associated likelihood should then be straightforward.
